Updating nuget package but in runtime still uses the old code
I have 1 project, which I build into a nuget package and another, in which I have installed this package. I updated the first project and then updated the nuget package in the second project. When I run the second project it still uses the old code, but if I go to the source code of the updated class with F12 I see the new code. If I step into it while debugging I see the old code and the location of the file is C:\Users\Maria\AppData\Local\Temp.vsdbgsrc\feb7085b11850d86ec767edd1961ad72682d40463f69e4b661f84d513154d2df. I have cleared nuget's cache, which didn't help, because this location is has nothing to do with nuget(I think), hence the problem isn't whit nuget caching. I also tried renaming/deleting the .cs file from said location, and then I can't step into it while debugging, but it still throws the exception that is fixed in the new version, so it's obviously still using the old code. I have recently updated VS to the newest version 17.11.3, if that has anything to do with it.
EDIT:
I fixed it by  copy/pasting the dlls from the first project's Release folder to the second project's Debug folder.
I am now having similar problem, but with System.IO.Port dll. I have it installed in 2 projects in same solution. The version of both is 8.0.0.0. One works correctly, and the other one throws error in runtime, that it can't find it. Copying it to Debug folder, deleting bin folder, Clean and Rebuilding solution does not help. After some of my attempts the error changes to "System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'System.IO.Ports is currently only supported on Windows.'". All of the projects are targeting Windows. When I go to SerialPort's source code to see where it is located this is what I see :

no matter wether I'm getting the unsupported error or the 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Ports, Version=8.0.0.0' error.
There is only one third party dll in this project : Zen.Barcode.Rendering.Framework and it has no dependencies.

please try to delete bin and obj folder of your second project and rebuild it to see if the issue persists.

I'm almost sure this was one of the many many things I tried with no luck, but copy/pasting the dlls from the first project's Release folder to the second project's Debug folder finally fixed the issue. I think this is a nuget bug, that came with the last VS update.

When you write "then updated the nuget package in the second project", does this mean upgrading to a new version of the package that was created after you "updated the first project"?  Basically, every time you change the package, do you also change the version?

@Maria, did you check the package version referenced in second project file?

Yes to both questions, I updated the version, then in nuget package manager I saw there is an update to the package and updated it.

I am now having similar problem, but with System.IO.Port dll. I have it installed in 2 projects in same solution. The version of both is 8.0.0. One works correctly, and the other one throws error in runtime, that it can't find it. Copying it to Debug folder, deleting bin folder, Clean and Rebuilding solution does not help

Please navigate to the nuget package folders and confirm whether there is the old version package. If yes, delete the old one and reinstall the new version. By the way, did you  use command  similar to   dotnet nuget locals all --clear to clear cache?

I checked the location and it was the right version. I deleted the folder C:\Users\Maria.nuget\packages\system.io.ports, deleted the dll from my debug folder deleted the System.IO.Ports.notsupported.cs file from C:\Users\Maria\AppData\Local\Temp and reinstalled the package, but the error persists

I haven't cleared the cache this time, but I tried it the first time and it also didn't help

I cleared nuget's cache, but I still get the same error

Looks like you have created a new ticket for the similar problem "Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Ports, Version=8.0.0.0" at here

Yes, I created a new ticket for the second problem, because it is different from the first problem and I thought they should be separated

You can add your solution for the first problem as an answer, it could help other community members who get the same issues issue to find the solution easily. Just a reminder :D

This is a workaround, not a solution, but I fixed the first problem by copying the dll from the first project's output folder, to the second project's output folder.
